# Apache segmentation fault

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, segmentation-fault

Ubuntu 10.10, Apache 2.2.16:

```
# service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                         Segmentation fault
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information
```

in log:

```
[  968.901395] apache2[1850]: segfault at 4 ip b76fafb3 sp bf824b94 error 4 in ld-2.12.1.so[b76f0000+1c000]
```

Reinstall don't help

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reinstall all apache packages(segfault apache-mpm, apache2 is metapackage)

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Try check md5sum:

```
sudo apt-get install debsums
sudo debsums -s
```

Also try use gdb:

```
gdb apache2
(gdb) run
```

Try backup config:

```
cp -R /etc/apache2 ~/apache2_conf
```

and delete package with config.

Comment: debsums: changed file /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-worker/apache2 (from apache2.2-bin package)

Comment: @hiemye try: sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2-bin

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but thank you, helped after deleting apache2_conf. Can you interpret what is happening? Why suddenly the segmentation errors?