# Apache fails to start due to Segmentation fault

Tags: apache-2.2, php, segmentation-fault

Please help me figure out why Apache2 will not start:

```
root@myUbuntu804ServerName:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2
Segmentation fault
   ...fail!
```

The application running on it is mostly PHP. How do I go about diagnosing and fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything in the error log? Did you add/load/compile new modules?

Comment: No, there's nothing in the log

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall apache2

```
sudo aptitude reinstall  apache2
```

found on (  [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/238947/apache-segmentation-fault))

Comment: Tried, that fails with a segfault too!

Answer (score 0):

What did you cachanged since the last sucesfull start ?

try strace/ltrace, try to disable the modules after each other